# PHP MySQL query result into a variable and then echo ($variable)

Tags: php, html, mysql

wish to check the last id (`cat_id`) in a table (`category`) and insert that result into a variable that I can echo.

My intention is to create a record last `cat_id` +1 as long as it doesnt already exist of course.

What I thought I should do was something like this;

```
<?php
   require "mydbdetails.php";
   $query="SELECT cat_id FROM category ORDER BY cat_id DESC LIMIT 1";
   $result=mysql_query($query);
   echo ($result);

 ?>
```

But oh no, nothing so simple. The `echo` was only to check I had the correct result (in phpmyadmin it returns the desired number)

Then I was hoping to be able to, with a simple html form, was to ask if the user wanted to add a category through a text box:

`addrec.html`:

```
<form action="addrec.php" method="post">
 Category: <input type="text" name="category">
 <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

`addrec.php`:

```
<?php
  require "mydbdetails.php";
  $new_id = $result + 1;
  $query="INSERT INTO category VALUES ($new_id, 'Fruits')";
?>
```

Comment: Be sure to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 It's not an answer to your question, but very important as you continue to learn php/MySQL.

Comment: Also don't forget that mysql_ functions are deprecated. Use mysqli_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first know as a developer, that mysql extension in php will be fully deprecated in the future as it is already in the newer php versions. So use instead Mysqli extension and PDO for sanitation and securer code for your database.

As it goes to your question:- Try the following ;

```
   // Make a MySQL Connection
   $query = "SELECT cat_id FROM category ORDER BY cat_id DESC LIMIT 1";
   //assign result to a variable
   $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
   //fetch result as an associative array
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
   echo $row['cat_id'];
```

You can assign it to avariable  `$row['cat_id'] = $catId;` like that and use it .

Answer (score 0):

echo $result[0]['cat_id'] i think

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using [PDO query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) Syntax instead of the old deprecated mysql_query.

If you make a PDO connection and store it in the `$conn` object ( pretty similar to what you already have in `mydbdetails.php`) just do:

```
   $query=$conn->query("SELECT cat_id FROM category ORDER BY cat_id DESC LIMIT 1");
   $result=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0);
   echo ($result[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should really be using `mysqli` instead of `mysql` because `mysql` is deprecated and will be removed in PHP 5.5.

Of course the PDO would be better, but i think that you're so new that it would be a bit to much right now.

Basically, you're firing a Query, but you don't tell the query to what connection. You're doing this:

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

What it should be is

```
$result=mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Where `$link` is the variable where you're setting up the database connection in the `mydbdetails.php` file.

Without the connection the Query doesn't know where to get the data from.

But if OOP isn't new to you, the answer from @amenadiel is better because it's an OOP way.

Further, there is no need for your `$new_id = $result + 1;` line.

IDs should almost always set to `Auto Increament` in the database, so this line will be done automatically in the database when you're adding a new dataset.

[More information here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
<?php
  require "mydbdetails.php";
  $query="SELECT cat_id FROM category ORDER BY cat_id DESC LIMIT 1";
  $result=mysql_query($query);

  $i;
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
      var_dump($row);  /* dump rows*/

      /* or add to array to use later */
      $results[$i] = $row; // add to array
      $i++; // +1 the counter to increment the array
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your scripts in [mysqli_](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.mysqli.php&ei=8iGXU8biJ5OyuATa3oCYDg&usg=AFQjCNFqRfUX_yzSi97oTFNFK8fyD3OsZQ&bvm=bv.68445247,d.c2E)  or [pdo](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.pdo.php&ei=CiKXU_DiHoq-uATW1IHABA&usg=AFQjCNEVPEYJeooD5as3cqYBNlYGSI9tPQ&bvm=bv.68445247,d.c2E) functions. Work around in mysql_ function (not recommended)

```
<?php
   require "mydbdetails.php";
   $query="SELECT cat_id FROM category ORDER BY cat_id DESC LIMIT 1";
   $result=mysql_query($query);
   if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      $cat_id = $row['cat_id'] + 1; 
   } else {
      $cat_id = 1; 
   }

 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

cat_is is the primary key? If yes you can set that column as auto increment. You can try this

https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Comment: That's not a answer to his Question, though you're right, but this belongs to the comments